# HTML clear button not clear text boxes text using jsp

Tags: html

Here, i my page have update and cancel buttons when i click cancel button text boxes text is not clear and how can i redirect to previous page.

my button:

`<input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="Cancel"/>`

Comment: Show more code (i.e. the form).

Answer (score 0):

How about just a simple reset button?

```
<form>

<input type="text" id="textfield1" size="5">
<input type="text" id="textfield2" size="5">

<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your input tag to :

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

And if you want to redirect to previous page after form submission:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("demo.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```